# Custom ViewResolver and dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-services

I'm attempting to create a custom `ViewResolver` class (extending angular's built-in class) to augment my systems' style metadata with a custom service (I'm loading my styles from external systems).  However I'm running into a problem with the dependency injection system and `ViewResolver`.

I have my system setup something like the following:

**Boot.ts**:

```ts
bootstrap(App, [
    MyStyleService,   // my custom service
    SomeOtherService, // another custom service used by MyStyleService
    {
        provide: ViewResolver,
        useClass: MyViewResolver  // my custom ViewResolver
    }
])
```

**MyViewResolver.ts**:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyViewResolover extends ViewResolver {

    constructor(
        private _reflector: ReflectorReader,
        // I want to reference 'StyleService' from the providers array in boot.ts
        private _styleService: StyleService
    ) {
        super(_reflector);
    }

    public resolve(comopnent: Type) {
        let meta: ViewMetadata = super.resolve(component);

        let styles = this._styleService.someMethod(meta);
    }
}
```

However inside `MyViewResolver`, `this._styleService` has NOT been injected and is currently `undefined`. It should be noted that `MyStyleService` also depends on another injected service `SomeOtherService`, so I need to make sure that that provider is also defined and available for the injector.

I want all of these services to be "provided" by the bootstrap, so that in the future I can provide alternate versions of any of my services on a per-system basis.

For reference this is angular's core `ViewResolver`:

**view_resolver.ts** (Angular2 core):

```ts
import {Injectable, ViewMetadata, ComponentMetadata,} from '@angular/core';
import {ReflectorReader, reflector} from '../core_private';
import {Type, stringify, isBlank, isPresent} from '../src/facade/lang';
import {BaseException} from '../src/facade/exceptions';
import {Map} from '../src/facade/collection';

@Injectable()
export class ViewResolver {
    constructor(private _reflector: ReflectorReader = reflector) {}

    resolve(component: Type): ViewMetadata {
        ... stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to configure your class with `useFactory`:

```
bootstrap(App, [
  MyStyleService,
  SomeOtherService,
  {
    provide: ViewResolver,
    useFactory: (_reflector: ReflectorReader, styleService: StyleService) => {
      return MyViewResolver(_reflector, _styleService);
    },
    deps: [ ReflectorReader, StyleService ]
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a charm.  It's not using the same "providers" stack as my main bootstrapped App, but I can still override dependancies at that level, so it works for my use!  Thanks again.